# How can a service on Server A copy files to Server B without domain-level authentication?

Tags: network-share, file-transfer

CruiseControl.Net is running on Server A (Win2003). It needs to copy some files from Server A to Server B (Win2008).  It needs to do this unattended, without any user being logged into either machine.

We are not running a Windows domain, so all user accounts are local.

CC has no "authenticated copy" task, so there's no way to get it to authenticate to Server B and just use a UNC path.

I could open up an unrestricted share on Server B, but that seems like a bad idea.

What are my options other than FTP?

(And, yes, I realize that this is a precisely what domain controllers are for... :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a user account on both machines with the same username and password (or mirror the user that CruiseControl uses over on ServerB).  Then create a share on Server B with permissions for that user to write.  The authentication sent from ServerA will be the username/pwd of the user, which will validate on ServerB as well.

Comment: Nice.  Thank you.  I had no idea credentials would pass like this.

Comment: You bet, that's what we're here for :)